# UISlider doesn't handle .touchUpInside event properly

Tags: ios, swift, event-handling, uislider, swift4

I have a problem that has been bugging me for the past day and I just can't figure out the solution...

I have an `UISlider`, which ranges from values 1 to 3 (thats the way we need it to be). The slider is continuous, because it actually updates some properties depending on its current value. Now I want to implement a feature where the slider triggers actions depending on wheather the user is starting to touch it, or ends the touch.

I tried using the `.touchDown` method to detect the start of touches, which works perfectly. However when I try using `.touchUpInside` and `.touchUpOutside` to detect when the user lifts of his / her finger, the event doesn't fire at the appropriate time.

When I drag my finger around the slider, a certain distance from its starting point, the event triggers. But when I just touch it briefly or move it around by a tiny amount, the touchup event doesn't fire at all...

Can someone help me with that? Here is the code I'm using to set up my slider:

```
let slider: UISlider = {
    let slider = UISlider()
    slider.isContinuous = true
    slider.minimumValue = 1
    slider.maximumValue = 3
    slider.setMinimumTrackImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "minimumSliderTrackImage").resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20)), for: .normal)
    slider.setMaximumTrackImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "maximumSliderTrackImage").resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20)), for: .normal)

    let sliderThumb = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "sliderThumbImage")
    slider.setThumbImage(sliderThumb, for: .normal)

    slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(adjustPriceLabel), for: .valueChanged)
    slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTouchDown), for: .touchDown)
    slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTouchUp), for: [.touchUpInside, .touchUpOutside])

    slider.setValue(2.0, animated: true)

    return slider
}()

@objc fileprivate func handleTouchDown() {
    print(1234)
}

@objc fileprivate func handleTouchUp() {
    print(5678)
}
```

Comment: So what you are saying is that you see `handleTouchDown()` be called and sometimes `handleTouchUp()` would not be called or?

Comment: Exactly. More specifically handleTouchUp() only gets called when I move the slider a certain distance from its starting position...

Comment: Can you try removing `setMinimumTrackImage`, `setMaximumTrackImage` and `setThumbImage` and test again to see if maybe your custom thumb images are to blame?

Comment: I tried it right now, it makes no difference unfortunately... When I tap on the slider or move it just by a bit, no event triggers

Comment: Do you maybe have any other gesture recognizers in the view or if slider is in a `UITableView`, `UIScrollView` or a `UICollectionView`

Comment: No, the only views that register touchevents is the slider and a button, which is located far from the slider. The only thing they share is the same superview which is a container for both. The container is a subclass of UIView

Comment: I also tried disabling the button and removing its target, but that didn't help either. It seems to be an issue with the slider... but I can't figure it out

Comment: What happens when you just tap on the slider...

Comment: Then only the touchDown event gets triggered... no touchUpInside or outside

Comment: Simulator or device or both?

Comment: Both unfortunately

Comment: can you add this `slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTouchUp), for: [.touchUpInside, .touchUpOutside, .touchCancel])` so adding ` .touchCancel` case

Comment: OH MY GOD! That did it! :D Thank you sooooo much for your help. The only question now is, why exactly did that help. Thank you again!

Comment: Will add it as the answer..consider accepting it as the answer :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should try adding `.touchCancel` state to go to `handleTouchUp` as well like so:

```
slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTouchUp), for: [.touchUpInside, .touchUpOutside, .touchCancel])
```

Comment: Perfect answer bro. Thanks.